# Parse not finding username

Tags: parse-platform

In my app, Parse collects an ID number as a name at signup or login.  I want to push notifications to all users who have that ID number as follows:

```
@IBAction func sendAlert(sender: AnyObject) {

    print ("Pushing for \(theIDNumber)") //this variable is correct
    // Create our Installation query
    let pushQuery = PFInstallation.query()
    pushQuery!.whereKey("username", equalTo: (theIDNumber))
    print(pushQuery!.whereKey("username", equalTo: (theIDNumber))) // this returns a value of <PFQuery: 0x15c7bc0d0>

    // Send push notification to query
    let push = PFPush()
    push.setQuery(pushQuery) // Set our Installation query
    push.setMessage(theMessageBlank.text!) 
    push.sendPushInBackground()
    print("Message pushed")


}
```

The result on the Parse website is that the push succeeds but is sent to zero people.  The Parse website does show that there is one person who has the requested ID number.

I see that the ID number does not appear in the Installation pane of the Parse data browser, and I see that I am setting up a PFInstallation query.  Is that the problem?  Changing it to a PFUser.query did not help.

Thank you,

Eli

Comment: So you didn't add and update the installation with `username` ?

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help!

Comment: You didn't actually answer the question though, it seems you're trying to use something that doesn't exist...

Comment: My problem was simply that I hadn't read the docs carefully enough. Had I read them, I would have known about saveInBackgroundWithBlock and channels.